# How to create a new text document from scratch and save it as .py file using cmd?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Without considering an option to open a notepad first and saving it with the extension ".py" , how to create a new ".py" file in a corresponding directory using cmd ?

Note : As a beginner python learner I request you to kindly ignore if this was a silly question ...

Comment: Have you searched for similar questions before?

Comment: Why on Earth would you want to save a text file as .py? Perhaps a Python script?

Comment: You can use `NUL> my_file.py` to create a file using windows command prompt.

Comment: `C:\>echo "my first python script ever!" > homework.py`

Comment: @Timir Thanks ,This gave a solution

Comment: You might want to read more about [output redirection from cmd in general](https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/redirect-output-from-command-line-to-text-file/). You can also use `echo "a new line"  >> homework.py` to append to a file, for instance.. `>` will delete all lines in `homework.py` if it exists.

Comment: To just create the file in bash, use `touch pythonfile.py`

Answer (score 0):

on windows:
C:\Users\username\Desktop> echo "the script" > hello_world.py

Note: replace the username with your actual user account.